# How do I check user sign-in status using the express-session?

Tags: angular, typescript, express-session

I'm building an authentication app using the PEAN stack (i.e., PostgreSQL - ExpressJS - Angular - NodeJS). For authentication, I'm using [`express-session`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) on the backend. Authentication on backend works 100% correctly.

#### Problem

**I have a problem regarding checking user sign-in status on the frontend (i.e., [Angular](https://angular.io/)).**

Knowing whether a user is signed in or signed out is necessary for mainly two reasons:

1. Angular components shown are different for the signed-in user.

   - For example, the navbar is different when a user is signed in.
2. Angular auth guard relies on sign-in status.

   - For example, only a signed-in user can access profile components.

Until now, I was checking user sign in status with `Local Storage`. When a user signs in, I set a key `is_signed_in` with a value of `1` in `Local Storage`. When a user signs out, I remove it. My whole authentication app was relying on `Local Storage`.

I had the following code in my **auth.service.ts**:

```
isSignedIn() {
  return !!localStorage.getItem('is_signed_in');
}
```

Then, for example, to show a certain button only to a signed-in user, I used the following code:

```
<button *ngIf="publicAuthService.isSignedIn()" mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="beforeMenu"></button>
```

**The problem is that when the session expires, `is_signed_in` stays in `Local Storage`.** Meaning that `express-session` works correctly but isn't coordinated with my `Local Storage` (obviously). In other words, the user doesn't see his/her data anymore (i.e., in the dashboard instead of *Welcome test.user@test.com*, he/she sees *Welcome*), but the navbar is shown as if the user is signed in, and profile routes aren't protected with auth guard (i.e.,  the user can still access, for example, the profile component although no data is shown there).

#### Question

I tried to get user sign-in status on the frontend, but I set the session cookie to `httpOnly: true` due to security reasons. Consequently, I can't use [`ngx-cookie`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie) to read it on the frontend and get user sign-in status this way. I totally understand why that is, and it's actually proof that the `httpOnly` cookie works as expected.

**My question is, how do I check user sign-in status so that when the session expires, the navbar is shown as if the user is signed out and profile routes are protected with auth guard?**